# List data from table created by many to many relationship hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 tables in my database: LOCALIDAD and CAJA. These tables have a many to many relationship, so sql server created a table to represent this relationship: LOCALIDAD_CAJA. I'm currently using hibernate in my project but hibernate didnt map this table, LOCALIDAD_CAJA. I need a query to list CAJA depending on the LOCALIDAD ID, so it goes like this:

```
select * from caja C, LOCALIDAD_CAJA LC, LOCALIDAD L
where C.CCAJA = LC.CCAJA
AND L.CLOCALIDAD = LC.CLOCALIDAD
AND L.CLOCALIDAD = 1
```

But in hql I can't access to the table LOCALIDAD_CAJA and I need to do this to make the match correctly.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm not using annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using annotations you can add an extra field to your many to many table, like modify date or something, so since the table now has its own attribute, besides the id's obtained by the many to many relationship, hibernate will automatically map them.

Comment: Indeed, hibernate mapped it correctly. But what if I don't need an extra field on the table? In which way can I make hibernate map the table without using annotations?

Comment: Which one is better by the way? Using the hbm's or annotations?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `@ManyToMany` with `@JoinTable` annotation

   You can use `@ManyToMany` association from `LOCALIDAD` to `CAJA` with
   `@JoinTable`. You can specify `name` of a join table and names of
   foreign keys with `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns`.
2. Using an additional persistent

   You can add a persistent for table `LOCALIDAD_CAJA` (for an example
   `JoinLocaliCaja`) and use `@OneToMany` associations from `LOCALIDAD`
   to `JoinLocaliCaja` and `@OneToMany` from `CAJA` to `JoinLocaliCaja`.